# How to make page content flow under top div

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a page with a top and side menu.

I've acheived the menu structure, but I can't get the page content to scroll under the top menu. At the moment, it flows over the top.

CSS

```
body
{
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

.fix-top-table {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px #39F solid;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 0px;
 }

.fix-left-table
{
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  border-right: 1px #39F solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}

#page-content
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="fix-top-table">
<tr>
    <td>
        This is the top table
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="fix-left-table">
<tr>
    <td>
        This is the side table
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="page-content">     
    Content<br />
    Content<br />     
</div>
```

I'm using tables as I personally find them easier to work with (dinosaur)

http://jsfiddle.net/6xmgrsyf/

I've tried z-index, changing position to fixed, nothing seems to crack it.

Many Thanks

John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont see the effect because you haven't set a background-color:
It also requires z-index...

```
   z-index:1;
   background-color:#fff;
```

Add this to .fix-top-table and It'll work.

Here's your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6xmgrsyf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `background-color` which makes the top menu transparent.

Just correct your css..

```
.fix-top-table {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  z-index:1030;
  border-bottom: 1px #39F solid;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try new css,

```
.fix-top-table {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px #39F solid;
     max-width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     padding: 0px;
     background: white;
     z-index:10;
 }

 #page-content
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Add z-index: 1; for #page-content and
add background: white; z-index:10; for .fix-top-table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

Added bg color and z-index:1

Works perfectly.

Thanks again